# How to add information to a request before approving or rejecting it?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-server

I am trying to create this small program in SharePoint where a group of users send requests to one admin then the admin adds up information to the request then approve or decline it. Then the outcome of the request must be shown back to the users. So I created a list with all the request info users shall fill in and I tried to hide certain columns from user where only the admin could view and fill in. But when I did that the lookup fields in which the user views his requests doesn't work so he can't view the outcome or whether his request had been approved or rejected since the fields are hidden.

Maybe there is another way around it or I could possibly use a workflow where it allows the admin to fill in certain information then approve or decline then takes the information back to the user?